# How can include a reference in a standalone ascx control?

Tags: asp.net, dll, ascx

I have an ASP.NET ascx control. In the code behind file I need to add some reference (Sharepoint Libraries) to do some queries. How can I do that? Is a standalone control, I mean I have only the .ascx and the ascx.cs files. They are not part of any project so I don't have the tipical Property folder in the solution explorer, and they are loaded in a sharepoint page using the SmartPart control. So I'm little lost here, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I put the dlls in a **\bin** folder at the same level of the control, I can use the code defined in it without problem. So I don't need to add a reference, by convention all dlls in that folder are available to my control.  More clearly the file structure is like this:

```
\UserControls\bin\AnyCompiledLibrary.dll
\UserControls\AnyControl.ascx
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't, In ASP.NET references are added to the web.config file of the application not the individual control. You would have to edit the SharePoint web.config file.